# Auto complete not showing result jquery

Tags: php, jquery, firebug

I am trying to create an auto complete using jqueryui.I am echo ing a database result  from the remote file search.php.It is showing the correct word in the response of fire bug but the suggetion list is not at all showing in my html page.
Can anybody please help me?

i'm using the code of [multipile ,remote](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) demo in the jqueryui.com

my php code

```
<?php include("connection.php");
 $q=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']); 
$x="select fieldname from tablename where fieldname like '$q%'"; 
$query=mysql_query($x); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo $row['fieldname']."\n"; } ?>
========================================================================

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <style>
        .ui-autocomplete-loading {
            background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            function split( val ) {
                return val.split( /,\s*/ );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
                return split( term ).pop();
            }

            $( "#birds" )
                // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                            $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.getJSON( "search.php", {
                            term: extractLast( request.term )
                        }, response );
                    },
                    search: function() {
                        // custom minLength
                        var term = extractLast( this.value );
                        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        var terms = split( this.value );
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push( ui.item.value );
                        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                        terms.push( "" );
                        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
        <input id="birds" size="50" />
    </div>
```

Comment: How can someone help you if we can't see your code? Are we suppose to guess what is wrong?

Comment: You will need to put some code here so people wont have to guess what is wrong. You have given no useful information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your remote file is placed on different domain you have to use JSONP. 
JSON dosen't support cross-domain data transfer.

Read more about [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: i am working in localhost and i can see  response under in firebug's response tab

Comment: i dont know much about JSON,can u please answer me why the response is showing under the firebug response,why it is not coming in the html page?

Comment: Instead of 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo $row['fieldname']."\n"; }
store $row['fieldname'] in variable
like $var.=$row['fieldname'].",";
and pass echo $var; outside loop.